# How can I remove this stubborn blue outline (<a> element) from iOS browsers (Safari & Chrome)?

Tags: ios, reactjs, accessibility, tailwind-css, outline

I'm using Tailwind CSS and React.

I've tried about everything under the sun to try and remove this blue outline from my <a>-elements in my page;

[This blue outline keeps appearing whenever I chose a menupoint and refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRKR5.png)

**My immediate thoughts came to :focus on the a-elements, so I've tried the following:**

```
.tabList {
  @apply mx-5 flex flex-row py-2;

  a {
    &:focus {
      outline: transparent !important;
      border: transparent !important;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) !important;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    &:focus-within {
      outline: transparent !important;
      border: transparent !important;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) !important;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    &:focus-visible {
      outline: transparent !important;
      border: transparent !important;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0%) !important;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried about every focus pseudoclass I can think off to try and target iOS, to no avail. Thing is, everything works just fine and I can actually manipulate and remove the border on my local machine (using ngrok to cast the developement port to my iOS device) and it doesn't come back. But whenever I push the same code to development and production, the blue outline keeps coming back. I even tried making the outline a different color (it worked) and iOS is **still** forcing the thick blue outline over my custom color outline.

I can't think of any relevant -webkit- css-classes I can use either. Many are deprecated or just plain won't work.

**Here's a snippet of the actual TSX:**

```
      <Tab.Group selectedIndex={getIndexOfSelecetedTopMenuItem(state)}>
        <Tab.List className={styles.tabList}> // Actual class
          {getToplevelMenuItems(state).map((item) => (
            <Tab as="div" key={item.menuItemId} className="basis-1/3">
              <ButtonTopCategory navigationModelUpdater={navigationModelUpdater} menuItem={item} />
            </Tab>
          ))}
        </Tab.List>
```

I'm of course keeping accessability in mind, but right now the blue outline is just plain interfering with the design of the page;

[Choosing a different (I've chosen the second point here) menupoint still keeps the first on in focus even after refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV0fm.jpg)

If anybody has experiences with this (I've Googled my ass off), help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I've tried several tested and tried methods to no avail; removing the outline (setting the value to 0 or none), making it transparent, changing the color (iOS forces the blue on it anyways), setting tabIndex prop to 0 or -1..

I expected the blue outline to go away when chosing 0 or none.

**UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE**

It turns out I was slaying the beast with the wrong tools. I'm using HeadlessUI for the tabs rendering, and it turns out I can use Tailwind CSS to apply styling conditionally. Whenever the tab was selected, I noticed the state of the Tab-component changed to "selected".

I looked up the Headless-UI docs and it turns out you can change the styling when the state changes. I applied "outline-none" as following to the Tab component;

`<Tab as="div" key={item.menuItemId} className={"ui-selected: basis-1/3 outline-none"}>`

Reference:
https://headlessui.com/react/tabs#using-data-attributes

Turns out the state was overriding the manual CSS!

Comment: did you try ```:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}``` ?

Comment: I did. I've tried "none", 0, transparent etc.. it actually works on my localhost but whenever I push the code to production and visit the site on iOS, it forces the blue outline.

Comment: Do you have a macbook ? If yes, you can connect your iphone to your mac, and inspect the code. Like this, you will see where comes from this outline, and then correct it

Comment: Really? Yes I have a MacBook. Do you have a guide on how to do this?

Comment: One of my collegue does it all the time, never asked him. Here : https://www.lifewire.com/activate-the-debug-console-in-safari-445798#:~:text=Connect%20Your%20iOS%20Device%20to%20Safari%20on%20a%20Mac&text=Select%20the%20Show%20Develop%20menu,debug%20console%20for%20that%20site.

Comment: `{outline: 2px solid transparent !important;
outline-offset: 2px !important;
}`

This is the actual styling I'm doing on a:focus when emulating on iOS and I've verified that it runs. But iOS still forces the blue outline.. even changing the color it still forces it.

Comment: The only thing I see, is to set the outline: none !important and make sure you call your css at the very end of your app. For example, if you call your CSS in App.js, make sure the import is the last one

Comment: @Johan I was finally able to solve this by conditionally applying styling - check out my update on the bottom of my post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great job. Np !

Comment: I’m worried about the `as="div"`. Are the [roles `tablist` and `tab`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#tablist) exposed correctly in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I’m posting your work-around as an answer.

**You should not do this without providing a reliable way to render [Focus visible](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG22/Understanding/focus-visible.html)**

It turns out I was slaying the beast with the wrong tools. I'm using [HeadlessUI for the tabs](https://headlessui.com/react/tabs) rendering, and it turns out I can use Tailwind CSS to apply styling conditionally. Whenever the tab was selected, I noticed the state of the Tab-component changed to `selected`.

I looked up the Headless-UI docs and it turns out you can change the styling when the state changes. I applied `outline-none` as following to the Tab component;

<Tab as="div" key={item.menuItemId} className={"ui-selected: basis-1/3 outline-none"}>

Turns out the state was overriding the manual CSS!